# Problem with Basic Authentication on Windows Azure RDP

Tags: azure, basic-authentication

I have hosted one WCF Service on the Azure platform and in web.config enabled basic authentication as per below

```
<system.serviceModel>
<services>
  <service behaviorConfiguration="SimpleServiceBehavior" name="RestService.RestServiceImpl">
    <endpoint address="http://localhost/RestWCFDemo/RestServiceImpl.svc" binding="webHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="secureBasic" contract="RestService.IRestServiceImpl" behaviorConfiguration="HttpEnableBehavior" />
  </service>
</services>
<bindings>
  <webHttpBinding>
    <binding name="secureBasic">
      <security mode="TransportCredentialOnly">
        <transport clientCredentialType="Basic"></transport>

      </security>
    </binding>
  </webHttpBinding>
</bindings>
<behaviors>
  <endpointBehaviors>
    <behavior name="HttpEnableBehavior">
      <webHttp />
    </behavior>
  </endpointBehaviors>
  <serviceBehaviors>
    <behavior name="SimpleServiceBehavior">
      <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" />
      <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false" />
    </behavior>
    <behavior name="">
      <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" />
      <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false" />
    </behavior>
  </serviceBehaviors>
</behaviors>
<serviceHostingEnvironment multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="false" />
```

On Azure it is not running. In local I have hosted this service on IIS and Enabled basic authentication only then it will ask for credentials when I will access it from URL, same way I have disabled all authentication methods except basic still I can't run this service  what could be the problem? Can anyone suggest a solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try adding a a proxyCredentialType to your transport:

```
<transport clientCredentialType="Basic" proxyCredentialType="Basic"/>
```

I would also set `includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true"` so you can see the problem better if that doesn't work.